# Failed with exit code1

Tags: ios

I'm trying  to build my project on actual device and I faced with this error. 
[image: Issue faced with my code]
I signed in my account and selected Team. I built successful my project on simulator device but not on actual device.

Comment: Check if your frameworks or libraries are built with a different swift version than the one you are using. The error log shows some info about "ABI version" issue.....

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and with <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

You can also clear your **Derived Data** from Finder by going to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and deleting the folder for the project (don't worry, this doesn't cause any issues!). To paste that directory in finder, you can use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In your screen I can't see the error log.
You did the cleaning (cmd + K) and deleted De