# Xcode Swift 4.2 Conversion Fails

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a project that builds and runs fine but won't convert to Swift 4.2.  It seems there are 2 folders "project name"Tests.xctest and "project name"UITests.xctest that I can't locate and are causing the conversion to fail.  I can't delete the folders or find them in finder.  I'm using Xcode 10.1. Any help would be appreciated.  A typical error is below:

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project name>-dksrhhtcudsdagageyofphmpyrgz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/<project name>/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<project name>UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/<project name>UITests.xctest/<project name>UITests'
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a copy of mine, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018883/failed-with-exit-code1/53020258#53020258):

---

Clean your project using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and with <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

You can also clear your **Derived Data** from Finder by going to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and deleting the folder for the project (don't worry, this doesn't cause any issues!). To paste that directory in finder, you can use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

This should fix any conversion issues. The error you received shows that the error is caused by the `DerivedData` folder.

Comment: I had cleaned the build folder multiple times without success.  But deleting the Derived Data eliminated 1 error on each of the .xctest files leaving 1 error on each now.  Can I safely delete the ModuleCache.noindex folder under DerivedData?

Comment: @zappullae Derived data is just the current data from your build. It should never cause problems. You can safely delete `ModuleCache.noindex`, but if you do receive more problems for some strange reason, you can just drag it back out the `Trash`.

Comment: @zappullae Do not delete any files **OUTSIDE** of the derived data folder, otherwise that **WILL** cause issues.

Comment: So it looks like this was a project problem.  I went back to the last saved version and the test products were different.  Somehow the code files for those 2 products were deleted.  I restored the older project folder and copied over the latest code files, deleted derived data, cleaned the build folder and rebuilt.  The conversion worked fine for the 3 products